# Branch x Checkout x Merging automatico para o master

Tags: git, merge

Help!

Se alguém já passou por isso ou souber ajudar, agradecerei.

1. criei um branch: `git branch <xxxx>`
2. alternei para nova branch: `git checkout xxxx`
3. alterei uma linha de arquivo dentro da branch `xxxx`
4. retornei para a branch master: `git checkout master`
5. Susto ==> as alterações feitas na branch `xxxx` aparecem na `master`

Saída do comando `git checkout master`:

```
$ git checkout master
M       WebContent/_footer.jsp
Switched to branch 'master'
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
```

Está fazendo o *merge* automático. Isso é normal ou foi algum erro de instalação? Alguém sabe desabilitar se for erro?

EDIT: Pessoal, agradeço pela ajuda, mas ainda não ficou claro.

Eu tinha certeza que as alterações da minha branch `xxxx` só apareceriam na minha branch `master` quando eu executasse o comando `git merge xxxx`, o que não foi o caso.

Vejam que por simplesmente trocar de branch ele fez o *merge* automático e é exatamente esse *merge* automático que não quero, alguém mais pra ajudar?

Answer (score 5):

Isso é normal e automático. Para evitar esse tipo de problema você deveria descartar as alterações feitas utilizando o comando:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Execute este comando com bastante cuidado, pois ele descartará todas as alterações feitas sem "commit". Para maiores informações leia o manual: `git reset --help`.

Como o Felipe Avelar lembrou é possível também guardar as suas alterações feitas no *stash* ao invés de simplesmente descartá-las. O comando para isso é:

```
$ git stash save 'descrição das alterações feitas'
```

Mas use isso só se as alterações valerem a pena, pois o *stash* poderá ficar bem comprido com o tempo. Leia o manual dele, também: `git stash --help`.

Outra opção seria utilizar o próprio `checkout` para isso, se você não tiver colocado as alterações em estágio de adição, ainda:

```
$ git checkout HEAD -- .
```

*Happy gitting.*

Comment: Ou ele pode commitar as alterações ou jogar pro stash também. (:

Comment: @FelipeAvelar Bem lembrado, adicionei na resposta.

Comment: Ou
git checkout -- :/

Comment: @MasterID Tem razão, adicionado.

Comment: Isso não é automático! Você não deve ter feito a mudança de branch... Você tem certeza que criou corretamente o branch? Certeza que foi para o branch correto fazer a mudança?

Comment: @egomesbrandao Sim, é automático porque ele não fez `commit` da alteração. Experimente: `git reset --hard HEAD && git checkout -b foo && echo foo > arquivo-ja-versionado-previamente && git checkout master && git status`

Answer (score 2):

O código que você modificou ainda não faz parte do branch `master`. Ele está por enquanto constando como código *modificado*, mas não está no *staging* ou no *repositório* (seja local ou remoto).

Para que você possa manter as alterações apenas no branch `xxxx`, faça o seguinte:

1. Volte para o branch `xxxx`: `git checkout xxxx`
2. Adicione suas alterações: `git add .`
3. Comite suas alterações: `git commit -m "(sua justificativa das alterações)"`

Pronto, as alterações que você fez estão apenas no branch `xxxx`. Para confirmar isso, veja as diferenças entre ambos os *branches*:

```
git diff xxxx..master
```